# I cannot load a prefab and cast it as it's type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am generating a set of prefabs during runtime. These prefabs are a simple Text UI object with an animator to create 'floating' numbers that appear above in game objects.

When I initialize the prefabs I can get them to load correctly from the Resources folder but once I get them in, I cannot change them from the generic `UnityEngine.Object` into my `FloatingText` type.

I have tried casting the object with a series of methods but nothing seems to work. I tried using `GetComponent` but that either throwm an Exception by invocation error or returns a null value.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FloatingTextController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private static FloatingText popupText;
    private static GameObject canvas;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        UnityEngine.Object temp = Resources.Load("Prefabs/PopupTextParent") as UnityEngine.Object;
        GameObject popupTextGameObject = temp as GameObject;
        if (!popupText) popupText = popupTextGameObject.GetComponent<FloatingText>();
    }

    public static void CreateFloatingText(string text, Transform location)
    {
        FloatingText instance = Instantiate(popupText);
        Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(location.position);
        instance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        instance.transform.position = screenPosition;
        instance.SetText(text);
    }
}
```

The above code is my Floating Text Controller object. The error happens when it arrives at `popupText = popupTextGameObject.GetComponent<FloatingText>();`

What am I missing?

Comment: have you attach the script into the prefab that is in the assets?

Comment: Yes the script FloatingText is attached to the PopupTextParent Prefab

Comment: why you don't load the prefab directly to the FloatingTextController?, you are using Resource.Load, but you could have the prefab as a field

Comment: How do you mean exactly?

Comment: what he means is why not having a `public FloatingText _popupText;` reference it via the inspector and later simply do `if (!popupText) popupText = _popupText;`

Comment: @user14492 has answered the question very accurately, read with attention, if you have any doubt, comment the answer.

Comment: Perhaps my way is the wrong way to go about it but all I need is for text to appear dynamically near multiple object that are being generated. This is why I created a prefab with text that I can modify. For each of these generated objects I need to set dfferent text.

Comment: and that's exactly what you could do using what I suggested. Simply drag&drop your prefab into the `_popupText` field in the Inspector of a `FloatingTextController` instance in your scene

Comment: @WilliamCalleja be sure to mark answer to solved if it has been.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things that are wrong here.

1. Why are you using a MB if the controller class is meant to be static. I don't see any non-static members.
2. You're loading the prefab file from resources and trying to get component on that. You cannot do that. You need to instantiate the prefab and get instance of the component. You cannot use the component from prefab file in any way. Use a public field to get ref to the prefab, you don't need `Resources.Load()`.
3. What you're looking for is [`GetComponent<T>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). You cannot simply cast the Game Object into your Monobehaviour type.
4. Then in your second function `CreateFloatingText` you want to instantiate a component object rather than a game object. Again cannot do that. You use `AddComponent`.

All in all, it's unclear what you're trying to do especially why you're doing it the way you're doing it. Google how to use prefabs and instantiate them to do it properly.

Comment: I have a number of game objects that are being created around my scene and I need some text that appears at their location.

Comment: @WilliamCalleja I got that. But it seems you're unclear on basics of prefabs and how they function. I highly suggest you spend some time watching tutorials to solve this. That will only take 10-15 min. but you can spend days on this issue if things aren't clear. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html